# center a div underneath another on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to center a div programmatically underneath another one when a certain div is clicked. I have tried everything with no avail so i need some help. Below is code i wrote. This the jsfiddle link for what i am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18656/

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class="box" ng-click="do($event)">
        <p> HEY THERRE </p>

    </div>
    <div class="box2" ng-show="show">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.show =false;

   $scope.do = function(evt) {   
        var $this = $(evt.target); 
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var width = $this.width();
        var height = $this.height();

        var centerX = offset.left ;
        var centerY = offset.top + height; 

       $('.box2').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': centerY,
            'left': centerX 
       });
        $scope.show = !$scope.show;

        console.log(evt);
        console.log(centerX, centerY);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `position: relative` on the `.box2` element. Also, add `margin: 0 auto;` to position it horizontally center.

This will cut down your JS code for positioning the element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/U3pVM/18657/)

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;

  $scope.do = function(evt) {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
}
```

```css
.box {
  top: 10px;
  right: 400px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box2.ng-hide-add {
  transition: all linear 5.5s;
}
.box2.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
.box2 {
  animation: slideDown .5s;
}
@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-20%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>

  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class="box" ng-click="do($event)">
      <p>HEY THERRE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" ng-show="show"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove your controller as follow:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/U3pVM/18659/)

```css
.box {
  top: 10px;
  right: 400px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box2.ng-hide-add {
  transition: all linear 5.5s;
}
.box2.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
.box2 {
  animation: slideDown .5s;
}
@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-20%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>

  <div>
    <div class="box" ng-init="show=false" ng-click="show=!show">
      <p>HEY THERE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" ng-show="show"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am trying to do it programatically not with css. My end goal is to mimick the Itunes playlist where you have your music displayed in a grid of several rows, and then when you click on a certain art cover it displays like a div with a tooltip that contains further details and actions for that particular track. So just imagine I have several li elements displayed on several rows, I want that when I click on one of them I would just place and absolute div underneath the bottom of the clicked li and I want the absolute div to be centered under the li.